# Datepicker and duration in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 fields 1: start date  2: End date and 3: Duration and I want to know how can I calculate like this  ( end_date - star_tdate +1 = duration ) 
my code works now but need to add one more day to count e.g 21 dec 22 dec as 2 day

this is my code:

```
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
$('#start_date, #end_date').change(function(){
    var startdate = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var enddate = $('#end_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var dayDiff = Math.ceil((enddate - startdate)/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    console.log( dayDiff  );
    if( dayDiff > 0 ){
        jQuery('#duration').val( dayDiff );
    }else{
        jQuery('#duration').val( 1 ); 
    }

})
jQuery('#duration').change(function(){
    var tmp = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate')        
    tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate()+parseInt(jQuery('#duration').val()) )  ;
    $( "#end_date" ).datepicker( "setDate", tmp );
})
```

---

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to already know the answer, a day is `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You should translate date string to UTC time before calculating.

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});

function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1;
}

$('#start_date, #end_date').change(function(){
    var startdate = new Date( $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate') );
    var enddate = new Date ( $('#end_date').datepicker('getDate') );
    var dayDiff = dateDiffInDays(startdate, enddate);

    console.log( dayDiff  );

});


jQuery('#duration').change(function(){
    var tmp = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate')        
    tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate()+parseInt(jQuery('#duration').val()) )  ;
    $( "#end_date" ).datepicker( "setDate", tmp );
});
```